# How to get notified about expired kafka events

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any mechanism to get notified (by a specific logfile entry or similar) in case an event within a kafka topic is expired due to retention policies? (I know this should avoided by design, but still).

I know about consumer lag monitoring tools for monitoring offset discrepancies between a published event and related consumer groups but they provide afaik only numbers (the offset difference).

In another simple words: **How can we find out if kafka events were never consumed and therefore expired?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log cleaner thread will output deletion events to the broker logs, but it'll reflect file segments not particular messages