# kafka message expiry event - how to capture

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a beginner to Kafka, and recently started using in my projects at work.  One important thing that I wanna know is, whether it is possible to capture event(s) when messages expire in kafka.  The intent is to trap these expired messages and back them up in a backup store.

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646676/how-to-get-notified-about-expired-kafka-events

Answer (score 2):

Messages don't expire. I think you could think of two different scenarios when you think about messages that expire.

1. A topic is configured with cleanup.policy = delete . After retention.ms or retention.bytes it looks like messages expire. However what actually happens is that a whole log segment, whose newest message is older than `retention.ms` or if the partitions `retention.bytes` is exceeded, will be deleted. It will only be considered for deletion if it is not the active segment which Kafka currently writes to.
2. A topic is configured with cleanup.policy = tombstone. When two log segments are merged, Kafka will make sure that only the latest version for each distinct key will be kept. To "delete" messages one would send a message with a key to target a message and with an empty value - also called a tombstone.

There's no hook or event you could subscribe to, in order to figure out if either of these two cases will happen. You'd have to take of the logic on the client side, which is hard because the Kafka API does not expose any details about the log segments within a partition.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the goal you want to achieve is similar to [Apache Kafka Tiered Storage](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-405%3A+Kafka+Tiered+Storage) which is still under development in Open Source Apache Kafka